# AiX topas snapshot to web

Tags: bash, networking, aix, xterm

My script for taking snapshot from TOPAS looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
whoami
export TERM="xterm"
(sleep 3; echo q)| topas -Emi 2 | \
   tr -d '\r'                                             | \
   sed 's/\'$'\033''\[[0-9][0-9]G/       /g'              | \
   sed 's/'$'\033''/\'$'\n''/g'                           | \
   grep -e '^en' -e '^lo' -e '^Network'                   | \
   awk '{ printf("%-8s%10s%10s%10s\n", $1,$2,$5,$6); }'   | \
cat
```

... fine tuning of removing special characters, and its result inside bash terminal is great:

```
root
Network       KBPS     KB-In    KB-Out
lo0         3652.9    1826.0    1826.9
en1         2133.4    2109.0      24.4
en2            0.1       0.1       0.0
en0            0.0       0.0       0.0
```

However, I wanted to shown it at my admin-web with simple:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain'); echo `myscript.sh`; ?>
```

But web result is bad (no network interfaces shown):

```
apache
Network       KBPS     KB-In    KB-Out
```

Wrapping SUID bit and managing to run it as 'root' does not help, same problem persists.
So I think that it is not a privilege issue.
Maybe it is something about TOPAS behaviour with TERMINAL (not sure what terminal $TERM should be to make this happen)

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Note the `apache` in your PHP script output.  The script is not run as root -- which is good, but may affect the way topas works.  Try `sudo -u apache bash myscript.sh` for comparison (if sudo is available to you).

Comment: @sr_ no, sudo is not available, but su - apache...run script manual is ok; also running from php over c-wrapper with suid bit shows root in result, but problem is same

Comment: Try explicit paths in your shell script, or set the PATH environment variable.